# insert date gap if date sequence missed in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have query below with period end date gap 14 days, it return correct output, but i want to insert missed period end date in query

```
Select *
From CURRENT_TIME 
left Outer Join
EMPLOYEE
on CURRENT_TIME.Employee = EMPLOYEE.Employee 
Where CURRENT_TIME.Employee = 'abc' and CURRENT_TIME.Period_End_Date > '2014-06-01'
```

it gives me output like

```
EMPLOYEE  Period_End_Date Amount
---------------------------------
abc        2014-06-07     100
abc        2014-06-21     200
abc        2014-07-05     100
abc        2014-08-30     100
```

But i like output like below

```
EMPLOYEE  Period_End_Date Amount
---------------------------------
abc        2014-06-07     100
abc        2014-06-21     200
abc        2014-07-05     100
abc        2014-07-19     null
abc        2014-08-02     null
abc        2014-08-16     null
abc        2014-08-30     100
```

help

Comment: Is the period end gap always 14 days?

Comment: yes it is always 14 days gap

Comment: @mukesh why dont you tried `inner join`?

Comment: @Prashant could you please send me query with inner join which give me missed dates, Btw i have to insert missed dates don't know how?

Comment: do you want to do this only with SQL; or perhaps with a PHP script  as well?